# Domain redirect .htaccess works only for subpages but not domain home

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set up a simple redirect from **laundrylane.com.au** to **laundrylane.com**

This is what I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://laundrylane.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works for every section in the site for example: **laundrylane.com.au/aboutus/** goes to **laundrylane.com/aboutus/**

But if I try to access the domain by itself **laundrylane.com.au** it redirects me to
**laundrylane.com/laundrylane.com.au/** instead of just the index, I tried multiple rules and combinations but I cannot get it to work, I think when the **$1** is empty it adds the whole URL

Comment: Ok since it works for the sections but not for the index... I created an Index.php with a php redirect, I'm not sure this is the best practice but it works for now

Answer (score 0):

**The below answer could potentially cause an infinite redirect for new domain...**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^laundrylane\.com.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://laundrylane.com [R=301,L]
```

This worked for me

Comment: you can see following url. it's very helpful for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57766416/common-htaccess-redirects?noredirect=1#comment101970872_57766416

or 

https://gist.github.com/garethjohnsdesign/8869dd1927df63fe70baf0e4e131ffc2